Antd Angular Tree Search behaviour?
I have a specific use case where I need to select only the matched node in search result even if we click on parent node, that meand only the searched node can be selected while clicking on parent node (parent can have un matched node)

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Find basic functionality here Tree Select. Currently if you search for a node and check on parent, it will all child nodes, what I am expecting is If I searched for a node and there may be chance is a parent can have 1-2 child node coming up in search result, so in this case if I will click parent only those 2 node should be selected not all the nodes
